# MSBuild /p:OutputType=Library builds as executable

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

My problem is as stated in the title: I'm trying to build my project from msbuild, and I specify /p:OutputType=Library, and the result is an executable application. I've been toying with this all day, and was able to successfully get it to build as a library twice, but unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce it since then.

I've been using this command:

`msbuild project.sln /p:OutputType=Library;Configuration=Release;Platform=x64`

Here's my vcxproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="driver.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="XMessageBox.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="accounts.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="udp.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="VersionHelpers.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="XMessageBox.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="project.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="UAC_shield.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{4D362A3E-CA53-444C-B1C8-C49641823875}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>project</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>11.0.50727.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <TargetName>project64</TargetName>
    <OutDir>..\x64\Release</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <MinimalRebuild>true</MinimalRebuild>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>EnableFastChecks</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <DebugInformationFormat>EditAndContinue</DebugInformationFormat>
      <BrowseInformation>true</BrowseInformation>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
    </Link>
    <Bscmake>
      <PreserveSbr>true</PreserveSbr>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>EnableFastChecks</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>MinSpace</Optimization>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <FavorSizeOrSpeed>Size</FavorSizeOrSpeed>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <DebugInformationFormat />
      <BufferSecurityCheck>false</BufferSecurityCheck>
      <BrowseInformation>true</BrowseInformation>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\Lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>false</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>false</IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>
    </Link>
    <Bscmake>
      <PreserveSBR>true</PreserveSBR>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>MinSpace</Optimization>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <FavorSizeOrSpeed>Size</FavorSizeOrSpeed>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <DebugInformationFormat>
      </DebugInformationFormat>
      <BufferSecurityCheck>false</BufferSecurityCheck>
      <BrowseInformation>true</BrowseInformation>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(PLATFORM_SDK_DIR)\Lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>false</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
    </Link>
    <Bscmake>
      <PreserveSBR>true</PreserveSBR>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
~P

Comment: Hmya, OutputType work well for managed projects, it does squat in a C++ project.  You'll have to get ahead by using ConfigurationType.

Comment: It sounds like that's my fate, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create multiple configurations that have the ConfigurationType property set to
the type of module you want to build, either Application or DynamicLibrary.

For instance you could have one configuration named ReleaseDLL that has
ConfigurationType=DynamicLibrary and one configuration named ReleaseExe
that has ConfigurationType=Application.  Then run

```
"msbuild project.sln /p:OutputType=Library;Configuration=ReleaseExe;Platform=x64"
```

or

```
"msbuild project.sln /p:OutputType=Library;Configuration=ReleaseDLL;Platform=x64"
```

depending on which one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm trying to indicate the output type based solely from my msbuild command, as I'm going to need to change it often.
If it's possible, that is.

Comment: You want to change the output type often?  I don't understand that I guess.  The project is always going to build a .DLL right?  If you put the ConfigurationType on each config then you could have different configs that have different ConfigurationType s and select which one to build from the command line.

Comment: I'm afraid not. My project has multiple entry points, so it can be built as a .dll or an .exe. I'd hoped to be able to control how it's built solely from the command line, but at this rate, I wouldn't be surprised if that's not possible.

Comment: Can't you just create multiple configurations that have ConfigurationType set?  ReleaseExe has ConfigurationType set to executable (whatever that value is) and ReleaseDLL with it set to DynamicLibrary for example?  Then run "msbuild project.sln /p:OutputType=Library;Configuration=ReleaseExe;Platform=x64" or "msbuild project.sln /p:OutputType=Library;Configuration=ReleaseDLL;Platform=x64"

Comment: That, my friend, is a wonderful idea. Thanks so much :) (Edit your answer to that and I'll mark it correct, and I'll also do my best to rephrase the question to fit it)